# How do i find the last <li></li> in every <ul></ul> (Front-end, html, css , jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, frontend

I have a menu with their own submenus too.

[image]

Problem: When the page is loaded, the **website emits a letter S** at the **end of every submenu**. 
How can i **remove** that **letter S** at the end of every submenu via JQuery or CSS?

This is the current markup when I copy html node in firebug:

```
<nav class="shopMenuHover">
    <div id="bx_incl_area_5_1"> 
        <ul> 
            <li class=""><a href="#" class="firstLevel"><font><font>Main Menu 1</font></font></a>
            <div class="shopSubmenuHover" style=""><h2><a href="#"><font><font>Sub Menu 1</font></font></a></h2>
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <a href=""><font><font>Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</font></font></a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a> s</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>


        <li class="firstLevel hasSubmenu instrumentarium-en-fresen">
        <a href="#" class="firstLevel"><font><font class="">Main Menu 2</font></font></a>

        <div class="shopSubmenuHover" style=""><h2><a href=""><font><font class="">Sub Menu 2</font></font></a></h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><font><font>Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</font></font></a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a> s</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        </li>

            <li style="display:none " class="firstLevel hasSubmenu emptySubmenu outlet">
                                        <a href="#" class="firstLevel">Outlet<</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

This is the jquery that i used to find the last li of every ul

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.shopMenuHover ul li:last-child').css( "border", "1px solid" );
  });
</script>
```

Kindly Please help me...

Comment: It would be better to find out from where this `s` stems from, rather than removing it after it has appeared.

Comment: This should be fixed on the server side - where the problem (extra s-letter) resides.

Comment: It is already there in your html so it will appear, Check your <li><a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a> s</li>

Comment: There's an extra 's' before the /li on both your menu items.

Comment: Post your code that generates the menu, there's likely an s floating around in that code causing the issue.

Comment: Hi, the letter S is displayed dynamically by the website.. I went to the menus but no S is found.. Please help...

Comment: On another note, what's going on with all those `<font><font>...</font></font>`?

Comment: Hi ljacqu, those are displayed after page load..

Comment: Show us the server side script, which generates the menu

Comment: The "s" is in the HTML script. Why can't you just remove it there? If the website is generated by PHP post the code for it please. Otherwise you can use `$(".shopMenuHover ul>li:last-of-type").slice(0, -1);`

Answer (score 0):

Use this one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
     $('.shopMenuHover ul li:last-child').contents(':not(a)').remove();
  });

</script>
```

Comment: To the explain the downvoter (I haven't voted on this answer, nota bene), it's probably because this problem should be tackled on the server-side — where the undesired `s` comes from.

Comment: You will need to share the server side script then.

Comment: _The poster_ will have to, yes, as he's been asked to do in the comments.