# How can I remove all text after the last <li> of every <ul>?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu with their submenus too. After the page loads.. The website generates random texts after every end of submenus..

[image]

This is the current markup that is generated from firebug:

```
<nav class="shopMenuHover">
    <div id="bx_incl_area_5_1"> 
        <ul> 
            <li><a href="#" >First Menu</a>
            <div class="" style=""><h2><a href="#">First Sub Menu</a></h2>
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a>
                    </li>

                    <li><a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a> 90797</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>


        <li class="firstLevel hasSubmenu instrumentarium-en-fresen">
        <a href="#" class="firstLevel">Second Menu</a>

        <div><h2><a href="">Second Menu</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><font><font>Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Sub Menu &gt; Sub Menu</a> 896346</li>
            </ul>

        </div>
        </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

**Problem:** The texts **90797** and **896346** are texts generated randomly by the website. How can I remove these texts after **every last li > a** inside every ul?

This is the current jquery i used to select **only the text inside a tag:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".shopMenuHover ul li:last-child > a").css( "border", "2px solid red");
});
</script>
```

**Output:** Remove all texts after a tag of every last li-last-child..

Please Help Me...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i find the last <li></li> in every <ul></ul> (Front-end, html, css , jquery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25505930/how-do-i-find-the-last-li-li-in-every-ul-ul-front-end-html-css-jque)

Answer (score 11):

You can select all the nodes, including the textnodes, with `contents()`, then use `filter()` to get just the textnodes outside the anchors, and remove them

```
$(".shopMenuHover ul li:last-child").contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).remove();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ujrp151h/)

Comment: Hi adeneo, Your code works.. May i ask again how this.nodeType===3 works?

Comment: @Redshot - it filters the nodes based on type, and 3 is the type for textNodes.

Comment: I see.. Thanks adeneo.. Hmm.. What if the website returns string of texts but not integers... Do you have an alternative way to do this?

Comment: Huh, it's the nodeType, it's always an integer, it's how a node is indentified internally? It's not the content of the node!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do this with CSS using the `visibility` property :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/hmswn29f/)**

```
.shopMenuHover ul li:last-child{
    visibility:hidden;
}
.shopMenuHover ul li:last-child > *{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

*note : use the `*` selector so it works even if the `<li>` contains something else than a link.*

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to set the `html` of the `li` to just the `a`.

```
$(".shopMenuHover ul li:last-child").each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.children("a"));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ujrp151h/1/

This would also clear anything else within the element other than the `a`, not just text nodes.